# Flex : providing data with a PHP Class

Tags: php, apache-flex, class

i'm a very new user to flex (never use flex, nor flashbuilder, nor action script before), but i want to learn this langage because of the beautiful RIA and chart it can do.

I watched the video on adobe : 1 hour to build your first program but i'm stuck :

**On the video it says that we have to provide a PHP class for accessing data** and i used the example that flash builder gave (with zend framework and mysqli). I never used those ones and it makes a lot to learn if i count zen + mysqli.

My question is : can i use a PHP class like this one ? What does flash builder except in return ? i hear that was automatic.

example it may be wrong, i'm not very familiar with classes when acessing to database :

```
<?php
class DBConnection {
    protected $server   = "localhost";
    protected $username = "root"; 
    protected $password = "root";
    protected $dbname   = "something";

    protected $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password);
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname,$this->connection);
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->connection);
    }

    function query($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'request error ' . mysql_error($this->connection);
            exit;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function getAll() {
        $req = "select * from servers";
            $result = query($req)
            return $result
    }
    function num_rows() {
            return mysql_num_rows($result);
        }

    function end() {
        mysql_close($this->connection);
    }
}

?>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically 3 ways that PHP and Flex can talk to each other. One is over XML, the other is over SOAP-based web services, and the last one is over AMF. The example you saw probably uses AMF but it might be a bit of overkill for you to use that.

What I'd do is just create a PHP file that outputs only XML and call that from Flex. The Flex code will look something like:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="srv" url="your_php_file_that_outputs_xml" />
```

You'll have to add a result handler and fault handler, but I think this will be much easier than using AMF.

=Ryan - ryan@adobe.com

Comment: doesn't it too "heavy" , i mean requesting + outputing in xml instead of just requestion datas ?
I finally managed to use the PHP Class preconfigured, but you're right it seems much more complicated than your solution.

Comment: Really depends on how much data you're using. For large datasets, AMF will be much, much better. But if you're not dealing with too much data, and you're new to Flex, XML is easier.

Glad you got it to work though!